# Lego Star Wars The Complete Saga: Chapter 3 Episode 4

Tags: lego-star-wars

I am trying to get past the part where Obi-Wan, Luke R2-D2 and C-3P0 are in a room with no door but a barrier. The barrier is holding the 2 droids back. How do I destroy the barrier?

Comment: Isn't this part in Chapter **3** of Episode 4?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Luke to destroy the side generators with his gun.